# How may I implement a generic, dynamically growing array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic, mixed

My requirements:

- The data structure must be able to hold an arbitrary number of elements (on the order of hundreds of thousands).
- The data structure must use memory efficiently. In this case, that means adding on an extra hundred thousand items whenever they are needed.
- The data structure must hold items of an unknown but uniform type.

The way I expected to be able to build one was to define a struct which represented the array. The struct contained the length of the array and the number of elements in the array. It also contained a pointer to an array of void pointers, which led to the actual data.

[image: Diagram showing conceptual layout of the data structure]

The pointer was used because the memory was malloc()'d and realloc()'d as the array grew. The array was of void pointers because the type of the elements was unknown. It was the responsibility of the user to create and initialize elements, to pass them to the array implementation, and to keep track what type was being used.

In memory, the struct would exist either on the stack or in the heap (user's choice), the elements themselves would be scattered throughout the heap, and the array of pointers to the elements would exist in the heap.

The problem is that when I went to implement this, I needed to be able to assign a void pointer to a spot in the array of pointers (e.g. when appending an element), and I could not do this because void pointers cannot be assigned (compiler says "incomplete type 'void' is not assignable").

Is there a different approach I should be using?

---

Nguai's code helped me get it right! His is below in his answer, and here is the implementation I wrote based on his code:

```
typedef struct {
    void **head;
    size_t used_size;
    size_t free_size;
    size_t current_size;
    size_t size_increment;
} GrowingArray;

GrowingArray createEmptyGrowingArray(int initial_size, int size_increment) {
    GrowingArray empty_growing_array;
    empty_growing_array.head = malloc(initial_size * sizeof(void *));
    empty_growing_array.used_size = 0;
    empty_growing_array.free_size = initial_size;
    empty_growing_array.current_size = initial_size;
    empty_growing_array.size_increment = size_increment;

    return empty_growing_array;
}

GrowingArray appendToGrowingArray(GrowingArray growing_array, void *new_element) {

    void *new_head_of_array;

    if (growing_array.free_size == 0) {
        new_head_of_array = realloc(growing_array.head, (growing_array.current_size + growing_array.size_increment) * sizeof(void*));
        if (new_head_of_array == NULL) {
            printf("Reallocation failure.\n");
        }

        growing_array.free_size = growing_array.size_increment;
        growing_array.current_size += growing_array.size_increment;
        growing_array.head = new_head_of_array;
    }

    growing_array.head[growing_array.used_size++] = new_element;
    growing_array.free_size--;

    return growing_array;
}

void finalizeGrowingArrayMemory(GrowingArray growing_array) {
    growing_array.head = realloc(growing_array.head, growing_array.current_size * sizeof(void *));
}

void freeGrowingArray(GrowingArray growing_array) {
    free(growing_array.head);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    GrowingArray test_array = createEmptyGrowingArray(5, 1);

    int *test_integer = (int *)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    *test_integer = 4;

    int *another_integer = (int *)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    *another_integer = 6;

    int *yet_another_integer = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *yet_another_integer = 9;

    test_array = appendToGrowingArray(test_array, test_integer);
    test_array = appendToGrowingArray(test_array, another_integer);
    test_array = appendToGrowingArray(test_array, yet_another_integer);
    finalizeGrowingArrayMemory(test_array);

    printf("%x,", *(int *)test_array.head[0]);
    printf("%x,", *(int *)test_array.head[1]);
    printf("%x\n", *(int *)test_array.head[2]);

    freeGrowingArray(test_array);

    printf("Going to free %llx\n", (long long int)test_integer);
    free(test_integer);

    printf("Going to free %llx\n", (long long int)another_integer);
    free(another_integer);

    printf("Going to free %llx\n", (long long int)yet_another_integer);
    free(yet_another_integer);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Completely broken at the moment, and not helpful to post. It's late here, so I will do a clean rewrite tomorrow morning that has the issue I talked about, and post it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code that is trying to give you an idea  what you have described.
By no means, this is a solution.
This is in a scale of 2, so you can stretch this.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 const size_t stIncrement = 2;

 typedef struct
 {
    size_t space_left;
    size_t size;
    void **vptrX;
 }T;

 T t;

 void
 vStoreData( void *data )
 {
    void *vptrTemp;
    size_t stMaxLength;

   if( t.space_left == 0 )
   {
       stMaxLength = t.size + stIncrement;
       vptrTemp = realloc(t.vptrX, stMaxLength * sizeof(void *) );
       if( vptrTemp == NULL ){
          printf( "Failed realloc");
         exit(1);
       }
       t.space_left = stIncrement;
       t.vptrX = vptrTemp;
   }

   t.vptrX[t.size++] = data;
   t.space_left--;
}

//This will make the memory efficient.
void
vFinalizeMemory()
{
   t.vptrX = realloc(t.vptrX, t.size * sizeof(void *));
}

int
main(void)
{
   int i;
   char c;
   float d;
   char *cp = "How are you";
   i = 10;
   c ='O';

   d = 40.12345;

   t.vptrX = malloc(stIncrement*sizeof(void *));
   t.size = 0;
   t.space_left = 2;

   vStoreData( &i );

   vStoreData( &c );

   vStoreData( cp );

   vStoreData( &d );

   vStoreData( &c );

   vStoreData( cp );
   vStoreData( &d );

   vFinalizeMemory();
   printf( "%d\n", *((int *)t.vptrX[0]) );
   printf( "%c\n", *((char *)t.vptrX[1] ));
   printf( "%s\n", (char *)t.vptrX[2] );
   printf( "%f\n", *((float*)t.vptrX[3] ));
   printf( "%c\n", *((char *)t.vptrX[4] ));
   printf( "%s\n", (char *)t.vptrX[5] );
   printf( "%f\n", *((float*)t.vptrX[6] ));

   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: How did this get downgraded?

Comment: What the heck!!! I get downgraded for trying to help!!!

Comment: This did it, thanks Nguai! I'll post the implementation I made based off yours.

Comment: The expansion should be by a *factor* not by constant.

Answer (score 1):

You want a pointer to an array of void pointers, not a void pointer;

```
void ** array_of_pointers_to_actual_elements ;
```

Good luck!